# no privileges on tablespace 'SYSTEM' ORA-00942

Tags: oracle, privileges, tablespace

i have this error when trying to create a table graphically:

[image]

> Creating table "ELEVE" failed.
> Failed Creating Table ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSTEM' ORA-00942: >table or view does not exist ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't do *anything* in the `SYSTEM` tablespace. As user you created doesn't have any objects yet, I suggest you drop it and recreate it, but this time by specifying another tablespace. For example:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL> create user ecole identified by ecole
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table to ecole;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

---

If you, however, insist on doing everything in the `SYSTEM` tablespace, then alter user and grant quota on the tablespace, e.g.

```
SQL> alter user ecole quota 100M on system;

User altered.

SQL>
```

Then create the table.

Comment: yes it solves me the probleme with alter user ...  ,   it's just a simple test i'll do like you suggested me on my project thank you

Comment: hello,  is there a way to assign two tablespace to a single user example: vehiculelocation for user and TableLocationVehicule, TableLocationVehicul1 for tablespaces ?

Comment: There's none, as far as I can tell, @Hikmet. "Default tablespace" is only one. **But**, you can specify different tablespaces for your objects. For example, when creating a table, CREATE TABLE statement allows you to specify tablespace which will contain that table. The same goes for e.g. CREATE INDEX.

Comment: i found a way that worked for me :  `code` `SQL> create tablespace meta_data datafile size 1m;  Tablespace created.  SQL> create tablespace data datafile size 1m;  Tablespace created.   SQL> create user user1 identified by user1 quota unlimited on meta_data   2  ;  User created. SQL> alter user user1 identified by user1 quota unlimited on data;  User altered.  --Now, the user can create objects on both of the tablespaces`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your execute user don't have privilege for System tablespace what's the default tablespace of execute user.

Comment: create tablespace ts1
datafile 'ts1_data.dbf'
size 2m;

create user ecole identified by hikmet;

create role role_ecole;

Grant create table, create session, CREATE VIEW
to role_ecole;

Grant role_ecole to ecole;